# Emulator crashing (NullPointerException) only on one computer when calling imageView.getDrawable()

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I run my app on the emulator on one of my laptops, it returns null for `imageView.getDrawable()` but if I run that same app/code on another laptop's emulator, it runs without issue and if I run it on an actual device, it also runs without issue.

This code:

```
if ( !(imageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable)) return;

//Clean up to free memory
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();

//THIS THROWS THE NULL POINTER (Which means the above line returned null)
bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
```

throws this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.PictureUtils.cleanImageView(PictureUtils.java:54)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onStop(CrimeFragment.java:251)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:1677)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:994)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:1924)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:613)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1212)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5376)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3185)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I figure out why this happens on this computer only? Here's the computers/devices:

### WORKING DEVICES

Acer C720 Chromebook (Chrubuntu Linux), 4GB RAM, Nexus 5 Emulator
Nexus 9 Tablet

### NON-WORKING DEVICE (throws NullPointerException)

Samsung Series 9 (openSUSE Linux), 8GB RAM, Nexus 5 Emulator

Comment: Well, getBitmap() returns null, not getDrawable() (otherwise your code wouldn't get executed)

Comment: with the same api levels?

Comment: @Elltz No, one emulator is 15 and the other 19, and the device is Android 5.0 (API 21). It's the emulator with API 19 (in between the two working ones) that isn't working.